# Removing n multiple items from a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

## Question

I want to remove items from a list such that I keep the first n items, and remove the next 2n items.

## For example

> for n=8, I want to keep the first 8, remove the next 16 and repeat this as necessary:
>
> a = range(48)
>
> Which I want to become
>
> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]

This is to pick out the first 8 hours of a day, and run a function on each hour.

I've found it hard to phrase this in search queries so the answer is probably simple but I've had no luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a comprehension list:

```
[ a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if (i % 24 < 8) ]
```

The above only create a new list. If you want to edit the list in place, you must explicitely delete unwanted elements, starting from the end to avoid changing indexes:

```
for i in range(len(a) - 1, 0, -1):
    if i % 24 >= 8:
        del a[i]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. The list 'a' is the same before and after this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
     def hours(n):
             items = [x for x in range(49)]
             del items[n:n*3]
     print(items)
```

`hours(8)`

Depending on how new you are you might have a hard time understanding this code, so I will try to explain a little:

We start by creating a function which takes a parameter `n` which, for test purposes, we will be using `8` then we use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions) to generate all our numbers (0, 48) and then delete the unneeded elements using [the del statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=del#the-del-statement), we are deleting from the `n`th to the `n*3` element in the list. For example, if `n` were to be passed as 9 our use of the `del` statement could be translated as: `del [9:27]`.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Ahsanul Haque Could you please elaborate a little more? I don't see how that's likely when we only generate numbers from 0 to 48.

Comment: For this, 48 was an example. n is a series of hours, and I want to perform a function that operates only on a certain series of hours. In reality I'll have a list of 10 years expressed as hours (!), and I want to perform the function on the 'night hours' i.e. 8 on, 16 off.

Comment: for `range(100)` run your code. You should get 36 element, whereas yours one will produce 84 element. In short, you need a loop. And you can avoid that list comprehension, rather do, `list(range(48))`

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite easy to understand

```
a = range(48)
n=8
result=[]
while a:
    result+= a[:n]
    a=a[n*3:]

print result
```